# JS, how to format a string with no delimiters into a date

Tags: javascript

So I have a date that I get from an external custom api, that comes in as plain string format with no delimiters.

How would I format it into a date.

String -> Date

20090506 -> 2009-05-06

I have browsed around stack overflow for a solution but it seems like all the answers revolve around a string with delimiters in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Basic regular expression](https://regexper.com/#%2F%28%5Cd%7B4%7D%29%28%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%28%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%2F) with replace.

```js
function alterFormat(ds) {
  return ds.toString().replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$1-$2-$3');
}

console.log(alterFormat(20200220));
console.log(alterFormat(20190220));
console.log(alterFormat(20201012));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to extract the year, month, and day, then you can use [`new Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to convert it into a Date object.

```js
var date = "20090506";
var formattedDate = `${date.substring(0, 4)}-${date.substring(4, 6)}-${date.substring(6, 8)}`;
console.log(formattedDate);
console.log(new Date(formattedDate));
```